# iOS web apps in the switcher

Tags: iphone, html, css, ios, mobile-safari

I would like to write a web application that behaves identically to transmission's (the BitTorrent client) web interface.

If you exit the web app, and then access the application switcher, transmission's icon is there.

All of the typical meta tags for ios web apps are leaving me with safari's icon in the app switcher.

Any ideas on how to achieve this behavior?

Comment: You can't do this. MobileSafari doesn't inherit the icon of its displayed pages.

Comment: What is this? [http://itslikebison.com/web-app-in-the-switcher.PNG](http://itslikebison.com/web-app-in-the-switcher.PNG)

Comment: Isn't Transmission open source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look at the [web app source code](https://trac.transmissionbt.com/browser/trunk/web/index.html?order=name) you can see what it's doing.

The magic sauce is

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
```

and

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="./images/webclip-icon.png"/ >
```

All of this is documented in the [Safari Web Content Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html)